# How to get DataGridViewComboboxColumn SelectedIndex keypress event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridview with combobox.

I can get the selected index of the combobox by using the following code:

```
private void dg_errorchart_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Control is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
            {
                ((ComboBox)e.Control).DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
                ((ComboBox)e.Control).AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
                ((ComboBox)e.Control).AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            }

            ComboBox cmbBx = e.Control as ComboBox;             

            if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl))
            {
                ComboBox comboBoxCell = (ComboBox)e.Control;
                if (comboBoxCell != null)
                {                       
                    comboBoxCell.SelectionChangeCommitted -= new EventHandler(comboBoxCell_SelectionChangeCommitted);

                    comboBoxCell.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(comboBoxCell_SelectionChangeCommitted);                      
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

But the issue is I can't get the index of combobox if it is selected by keyboard. How can I do that?

UPDATE:

I just added another event handler for combobox and catch enter manually and increase the row id.

```
cmbBx.KeyUp -= new KeyEventHandler(cmbBx_KeyUp);
cmbBx.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(cmbBx_KeyUp);
```

and in the event handler i added :

```
DataGridViewCell currentCell = dg_errorchart.CurrentCell;
if (currentCell != null)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl cmbBx = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
    if (cmbBx.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        int nextRow = 0;
        nextRow = currentCell.RowIndex + 1;
        if (nextRow >= dg_errorchart.Rows.Count)
        {
            nextRow = nextRow - 1;
        }

        DataGridViewCell nextCell = dg_errorchart.Rows[nextRow].Cells[6];
        dg_errorchart.CurrentCell = nextCell;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Suressh

Comment: Does it work when you `TAB` out from the control, since the change is not committed till then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to handle this in **SelectedIndexChanged** event handler?

Add SelectedIndexChanged event handler into dg_errorchart_EditingControlShowing method, at the same place as *SelectionChangeCommitted* handler.

```
comboBoxCell.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(comboBoxCell_SelectedIndexChanged);
comboBoxCell.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboBoxCell_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Then in comboBoxCell_SelectedIndexChanged method you will be able to get selected index or value from the combobox.

```
private void comboBoxCell_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox conboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    int index = conboBox.SelectedIndex;
    if (index > -1)
    {
        label1.Text = conboBox.SelectedValue + ": " + conboBox.Text;
    }
}
```

This's working for me, although user choose an item by keyboard.

Comment: Thanks Motomoto.. But the issue is user has to press double enter to select an item and move to next row. can it be reduced to single enter to select the current selection and move to next row??

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve that, I will get back to you when I have a time. Thanks.

Comment: @Suressh No, double enter is required here, as the control needs focus to be selected. In this case, the combobox is inside ComboBoxColumn. So, after 1st enter, the Column is selected. Then after 2nd enter, combobox gains focus.

Comment: @Wasif Hossian, I got your point. But my requirement is like that. My client will have more than 15-20 records. they want to type first char of combobox item and press enter, so corresponding record is selected and move to next row. they feel double enter is time consuming. thanks

Comment: @Suressh Then I think you need to use Grid Control from some 3rd party e.g. Devexpress, [Wpf Extended Datagrid](http://wpfextendeddatagrid.codeplex.com) on Codeplex etc, as the Winforms DataGridView does not support this direct focus.